# How can I select a certain user with an ID to DM? Discord.js 1.46

Tags: javascript, discord.js, dm

This is what I tried:

```
if (!message.member.username.cache.find) === "Duck"))
  return message.channel.send('You dont have permissions to use this command.')
```

Basically it got a lot of errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get an user via his ID and DM him you can do this:

```
let member = message.guild.members.cache.get('ID of the user to DM');
member.user.send('your message');
```